# complex square matrix unitarily equivalent to its Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

Help me please, is every complex square matrix unitarily equivalent to it's Jordan normal form? ( $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent if $A=UBU^{*}$, when U is unitary matrix )

Comment: no, and that's also the reason why there are diagonalizable non-normal matrices

Comment: notice: there are counterexamples already among $2\times 2$ matrices

Comment: You should prove that is not unitarily equivalent to its Jordan Form. That is not entirely trivial. Try instead to find a non-hermitian matrix, that has real distinct eigenvalues. That is 100% a counterexample